# How do I sent an Intent from one of my Apps to another of my Apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a class `IntentService` which in `com.mypackage.app1.receiver` (the first App):

```
public class IntentService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.w("INTENT SERVICE", "Received request to start intent");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the manifest I register:

```
<service android:name=".IntentService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mypackage.START_INTENT"/>
        <category android:name="com.mypackage.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

In the other App I have `SenderActivity` in `com.mypackage.app2.sender` that's simply supposed to start send the intent when opened and close immediately:

```
public class SenderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.learningleaflets.START_INTENT");
        intent.setPackage("com.mypackage");
        startService(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, currently the intent that `SenderActivity` sends doesn't get received by `IntentService`. What do I have to do, to get it received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
<service android:name=".IntentService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mypackage.START_INTENT"/>
        <category android:name="com.mypackage.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

with:

```
<service android:name=".IntentService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.learningleaflets.START_INTENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

to match your `Intent` that you are using with `startService()`.

Also, since there is an Android SDK class named `IntentService`, I recommend that you change the name of your service to something else.